# Converting Excel data to notepad

Tags: vba, excel, notepad

Whenever I run the macro text file is generated but there is space after every line., How do I fix it?

Here it is my code

```
Sub test()
    Dim txt As String, i As Long, rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:C500")
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        With WorksheetFunction
            txt = txt & vbCrLf & Join(.Transpose(.Transpose(rng.Rows(i).Value)), vbTab)
        End With
    Next
    Open "c:\test\test.txt" For Output As #1
        Print #1, Mid$(txt, 2)
    Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the output example your getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Trim`ing the text. The code should be something like this:

```
txt = txt & vbCrLf & Trim(Join(.Transpose(.Transpose(rng.Rows(i).Value)), vbTab))
```